# Link dynamic shared library in Linux - Undefined reference to function

Tags: c++, linux, reference, export, dynamic-library

I know there are many questions related to shared libraries on Linux but maybe because I'm tired of having a hard day trying to create a simple dynamic library on Linux (on Windows it would have taken less than 10 minutes) I can't find what happens in this case.
So, I am trying to create a library to be linked at build-time and used at run-time (not a static library, not a library to be embedded into the executable, in other words). For now it contains a simple function. These are my files:

1.

```
// gugulibrary.cpp
// This is where my function is doing its job

#include "gugulibrary.h"

namespace GuGu {
    void SayHello() {
        puts("Hello!");
    }
}
```

2.

```
// gugulibrary.h
// This is where I declare my shared functions
#include <stdio.h>

namespace Gugu {
    void SayHello();
}
```

3.

```
// guguapp.cpp
// This is the executable using the library
#include "gugulibrary.h"

int main() {
    GuGu::SayHello();
    return 0;
}
```

This is how I try to build my project (and I think this is what is wrong):

```
gcc -Wall -s -O2 -fPIC -c gugulibrary.cpp -o gugulibrary.o
ld -shared -o bin/libGugu.so gugulibrary.o
gcc -Wall -s -O2 guguapp.cpp -o bin/GuGu -ldl
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=bin
```

This is saved as a .sh file which I click and execute in a terminal. The error I get when trying to link the library is this:

```
/tmp/ccG05CQD.o: In function `main':
guguapp.cpp:(.text.startup+0x7): undefined reference to `SayHello'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And this is where I am lost. I want the library to sit in the same folder as the executable for now and maybe I need some symbols/definitions file or something, which I don't know how to create. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like you are missing `-lGugu`

Comment: Why `gcc`? Why not `g++`?

Comment: O.K. but I don't think that will solve the problem. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: Also, it is not clear (to me), what is the point of `extern C` when non-C constructs like `namespace` is used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inconsistent with your GuGu, there are also Gugu's running around, this needs to be made consistent, then it works (At least on my computer are some Gugu's now)

Comment: and, of courese, you neet to add libGugu.so: `g++ -Wall -s -O2 guguapp.cpp bin/libGugu.so -o GuGu -ldl`

Comment: You mean I can't just create a .so file for the executable, place it in the same directory and voila?

Comment: No, you can also do it like that: `gcc -Wall -s -O2 -fPIC -c gugulibrary.cpp -o gugulibrary.o`
`ld -shared -o bin/libGugu.so gugulibrary.o`
`gcc -Wall -s -O2 guguapp.cpp -Lbin -lGugu -o GuGu -ldl`
Note that you have to omitt the `.so`extension to make it work,

Comment: Almost there. Now I get a symbol lookup error when executing the application using the library (./GuGu).

Comment: ...which has been fixed by adding extern "C"

Comment: Thanks! What do you exactly mean by "inconsistent"? In Windows you can create a dll and have/use it from the same folder as the executable. In Linux .so files are stored in usr/lib or other filesystem folder, as libLibName.so.1.0 or similar name. Is this the only way?

Comment: No, just add -L. to link it in from the current dir, and do something like `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: With inconsistent I meant that you sometimes write(wrote) the second G in Gugu capitalized, sometimes not

Answer (score 2):

In your C++ file, `GuGu::SayHello` is declared as a C++ symbol.  In your header, you are wrapping it in an `extern "C"` block.  This is actually undefined, as you aren't allowed to use C++ syntax (`namespace`) in that context.  But my guess is that what the compiler is doing is ignoring the namespace and generating a C symbol name of "SayHello".  Obviously such a function was never defined by your library.  Take out the `extern "C"` bits, because your API as defined cannot be used from C anyway.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed something but still having a problem: error while loading shared libraries: bin/libGuGu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: The directory containing libGuGu.so should appear on your LD_LIBRARY_PATH